# convert value data from table using php function

Tags: php, mysql, function

suppose I have a mysql table like following:

```
CREATE TABLE `jurnal`(
`IDJurnal` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`volume` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`nomor` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`bulan` INT(2)NOT NULL,
`tahun` INT(4)NOT NULL,
`halaman` INT(4)NOT NULL,
`issn` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`pengantar` text NOT NULL,
`redaksi` text NOT NULL,
`cover` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`updated_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`IDJurnal`))ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

value data from column 'bulan' is '11', for example

How can I convert them to a string like this:

```
November
```

using php function ?
any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if value from 'bulan' = 1, it will be January, 2, it will be=February,....

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("m",11)->format("F");
                                    ^---------------------- Month Value
```

Output

```
November
```

[Tested on `PHP 5.3.0 - 5.4.9`](http://3v4l.org/Ujbmh)

Comment: this is my full code, foreach ($jurnal as $key => $list) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $list['IDJurnal'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td>Volume " . $list['volume'] . "&nbsp; Nomor " . $list['nomor'] . "&nbsp; Bulan " . $list['bulan'] . "&nbsp;Tahun " . $list['tahun'] . "&nbsp;</td>\n";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $list['nama_pengarang'] . "</td>\n";
            echo "<td align='center'>";

Comment: for example if $list['bulan']=1, it will be January

Answer (score 0):

Use the php strtotime and date function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you know you are retrieving a month, drop it into a real date like 2012-**11**-01, and convert that datetime string to a word-month using php's date function

date('F',strtotime('2012-**11**-01')) will return 'November'

Comment: I mean, for example, if the data coming out of the 'bulan'=1, it will be January

Comment: Yes, this should do that. put the parameter for the strtotime function as date('F',strtotime('2012-' . $list['bulan'] . '-01')) and it will return the name of the month, if bulan = 1, it returns January, if bulan = 11 it returns November, if bulan = 3, it return March, etc etc...